# Why is this line connected to the microcontroller input in this schematic?

Tags: mosfet, relay

I found this wheelchair board and am trying to dissect some parts. I don't have many fancy tools so am just using continuity test to trace what goes where and this piece belongs to relay control circuit.

where uC is microcontroller input/output. What is the purpose of D1 and D4?

**Before:** <strike>What is the purpose of this specific piece (highlighted in red). Why is the relay pin 85 connected to the microcontroller. I know the diodes are for protection but what else?</strike>

[image]

here is the actual image from the board:
[image]
*Edit*: I renamed the diodes and also refactored the circuit a bit.

Comment: The way you have drawn the schematic may be tricking you.  The only thing those diodes and the uC connections have in common...is common.  It looks like the uC pins don't have anything to do with the relay.  Those diodes may just be free wheeling diodes to suppress voltage surges when the relay turns off.

Comment: How sure are you this schematic is correct?  I see several questionable elements.

Comment: that's actually a good point. But what is D3 and D2 doing? right by the relay.

Comment: I believe those are also to prevent voltage spikes when the relay opens.

Comment: @evildemonic, I am not very positive as i am tracing this by looking at the board and then doing continuity tests. And I am also checking here with the community to see if it makes sense.

Comment: ... in passing, I see four D2.  It looks as if perhaps you're using a drawing package rather than a schematics program; I'd recommend changing if so.

Comment: @jonathanjo, thanks for pointing that out. I would change that.

Comment: @evildemonic Doesn't do anything to protect the PNP transistor though. Unless Q2 and Q5 are meant to interrupt the relay coil current while the PNP stays closed the entire time.

Comment: on the actual smd part for D1/D4 is says A4t 17 which seems to be a BAV70 dual diode.

Comment: @DKNguyen Agreed, I feel like we are missing something here.  Why aren't the diodes connected directly across the coil?  Kevin's answer makes sense, but it seems like it could be simpler.

Comment: @DKNguyen I added the actual image from board.

Comment: @evildemonic i added actual image from board

Answer (score 1):

They are to avoid excessive inductive voltage pulses when the PNP transistor is stops conducting to allow the relay to turn off.

When Q4 and Q2 or Q5 are turned on the PNP transistor will conduct and apply voltage to the relay coil.

When the PNP transistor turns off the current in the relay coil will reduce, but its inductance will cause a voltage backswing that in this case will make the collector of the transistor fall down to zero and attempt to go negative. D1 and D4 will start conducting then and prevent a damaging voltage across the transistor.

If the relay is turned off by Q2 or Q5 ceasing to conduct a similar action will occur only in this case the drain of Q2/Q5 will go positive; D2 and D3 prevent the voltage going above the 24V rail.